# SQL composite key syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a composite key for MYSQL, but i dont know how to, ive tried the following;

```
CREATE TABLE order_line(
order_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
car_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (order_id, car_id));

ALTER TABLE order_line ADD CONSTRAINT order_line_FK FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders (order_id);
ALTER TABLE order_line ADD CONSTRAINT order_line_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (car_id) REFERENCES car (car_id);
```

Comment: why would you `auto_increment` the foreign keys ?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i was able to do it like;

```
CREATE TABLE order_line (
order_id int NOT NULL,
car_id int NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE order_line ADD CONSTRAINT order_line_PK PRIMARY KEY (order_id, car_id);
ALTER TABLE order_line ADD CONSTRAINT order_line_FK FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders (order_id);
ALTER TABLE order_line ADD CONSTRAINT order_line_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (car_id) REFERENCES car (car_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

you cant have autoincremented key.
See this example of yours makes no sense, on the key you are saying that order_id  references orders (order_id), which is fine, but on the table you are saying that this same value is auto-increment, which means that it will be generated by the database.

Remove both AUTO_INCREMENT from your order_line table and you should be fine

if you want you can have a AUTO_INCREMENT order_line_id field on your order_line table as a primary key (which I recommend)

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL you can have only one AUTO_INCREMENT column so you can't define a composite key as AUTO_INCREMENT. Have you tried just

```
CREATE TABLE order_line(
  order_id int NOT NULL,
  car_id int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (order_id, car_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

`CONSTRAINT composite_key_name PRIMARY KEY (col1,col2)`